# docker restart on cascade

Tags: connection, docker, containers, cascade, restart

We've found that, if you have two containers linked, and network connections established between them, if the receiving container is restarted, the other one maintain the connections alive, resulting in failures.

Our question is: Is it possible to restart containers in cascade?

eg:

- Container_A -link-> Container_B
- Container_B is restarted
- Container_A is restarted in cascade because of Container_B was restarted

Thank you in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to write a script, which either looks at `docker events` and restarts Container_A when needed, or note the id of container B, and when in `docker ps -q` you do not find it, restart container_A

Answer (score 0):

if you use systemd with service units u make one service dependant on other:

for example I have my custom web application with nginx in front, so when I define nginx.service

```
[Unit]
After=vcl.service
Requires=vcl.service
```

...

this way when my vcl service is restarted systemd restarts nginx. Probably u can set upstart to make something similar. So answer to your question is - use some init service.